# Yahoo! Finance API: Get Stock Quote in EUROS

Tags: yahoo-finance

I'm trying to use the Yahoo! Finance API to get stock quotes on companies from the German exchange XETRA in Euros. However, I always end up with the share price in US dollars.

I'm using the following query: http://de.finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?s=AAPL&f=l1

This gives me the correct value from the correct exchange but it's in dollars as opposed to Euros.

Can anyone help?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how to directly do this, but:

http://quote.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?s=USDEUR=X&f=l1

will return the real time exchange rate of US dollars to Euros.  If it were me I would write a function that would multiply the dollar amount by the exchange rate.

note:
I found

http://brusdeylins.info/tips_and_tricks/yahoo-finance-api/

to be quite helpful. In his example he has "&f=nl1d1t1" which returns the n for the name ("USD/EUR"), l1 the rate, d1 the date, t1 the time.

I hope this helps.